# Date/Time Field Being Passed Via Integration

Tags: apex, integration, data-loader

We are passing date/time values from another system to a custom date/time field in Salesforce, and having timezone issues.

We're passing in the org's timezone, which is central time, but it seems Salesforce updates the value as it displays 5 hours later.

Do we need to pass all date/time values in GMT, then let they system update to the proper timezone?

Comment: Yes pass as GMT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when datetime values are passed via the api, they are assumed to be in GMT.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004680